# Arc Length of an Ellipse

Tags: calculus, elliptic-integrals

An ellipse has parametric representation $x = a\cos t$, $y = b \sin t$ for $0 ≤ t ≤ 2\pi$. Can you
write a formula for its total length? Do not waste your time trying to calculate it.

The way I was thinking to approach is basically gives me the formula for any ellipse

$$F(a,b)=\int_0^{2\pi}\!\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}\,dt$$

but I don't think this is the right approach

Comment: $\displaystyle\;F(a,b) = 4aE\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}\right)$ where $E(e)$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: What you have *is* the right approach. Are you having trouble evaluating that integral? You should! There's no way to express that integral in terms of elementary functions. This is what the note "Don't waste your time" is referring to.

Comment: What bothers you about your expression? There is a standard formula for arclength of a curve given parametrically, and you used it correctly.

Comment: Thanks! :) I was just worried, as I saw it like the answer came out too easily

Answer (score 5):

If you read carefully the wikipedia page, you'll find an expression for the complete elliptic integral of the second kind that reads :

$$E(k) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \! \sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

#### First remark: limits of integration.

You can slice your integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ into four parts that will describe the same arc of ellipse. Your are then left with the following integral :

$$F(a,b) = 4 \int_0^{\pi/2} \! \sqrt{a^2 \sin(t) + b^2 \cos(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t $$

#### Second remark : parametrization and relation between $a$ and $b$.

You must first check whether $a \ge b$ or $b < a$. Your parametrization of the ellipse will depend on it, especially if you want to fall back on the same form of $E(k)$ as the one given above.

In the general case, we suppose $a$ to be the semi-major axis, therefore $a \ge b$. In that case, your parametrization won't give you the expected result right away, you'll have to use a change of variable $s = \pi/2-t$. This amounts to the same as using the following parametrization:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = a \sin(t)\\
y = b \cos(t)
\end{cases}
$$

Then you'll get (using $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$) :

$$
F(a,b) = 4a \, E(k)
$$
with $k^2 = \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a^2}=e^2$ with $e$, the eccentricity. The values of $E(k)$ are computed numerically.