# Geometric interpretation of the elliptic integrals

Tags: integration, geometry, elliptic-integrals

The elliptic integrals seem to be constructed in a similar manner to the trigonometric and hyperbolic ones. We take a shape, in the elliptic case, an ellipse.
$$\Delta= \sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}$$
Then we invert and put in an integral.
$$\int \frac{1}{\Delta}$$
And then we get a set of Inverse functions.
What is the geometric interpretation of taking a shape inverting it(in the fraction sense) taking an integral and then finding the resulting function’s inverse?
This might involve the inverse function theorem.
Moreover, is it useful to do this for other shapes? Such as the hyperbolic counterpart of an ellipse?

Comment: Remark: doing this on the line $\Delta = x$ we get the exponential function.

Comment: When dealing with integrals people realized very early on (without proof) that some functions don't have elementary anti-derivatives so they started studying the integrals directly as a function. It took the genius of Abel to invert those integrals and lead to a deep and rich theory of elliptic functions in the special case you mention. These things are not as self evident as they appear now.

Comment: @Paramanand, But, the way I outlined is for a general function, not the elliptic case in private.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805541/arc-length-of-an-ellipse

Comment: Thanks, anything about the other part of the question?