# Sine wave on ellipse.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, parametric

I want to evenly draw a sine wave around the circle and ellipse.
Here's for circle:
$r$ is radius, $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, 20 is no. of waves.
$x = (r + \sin(20t))\cos(t)$
$y = (r + \sin(20t))\sin(t)$

[image]

Now I want to draw the same thing for ellipse **evenly**
Here's for ellipse:
$a$ and $b$ are major and minor axis, $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, 20 is no. of waves.
$x = (a + \sin(20t))\cos(t)$
$y = (b + \sin(20t))\sin(t)$

[image]

As you can see, the waves are concentrated at the ends but I want it to be evenly distributed. I prefer elementary function as I want to keep computation cheap. Accuracy is not important in my case, even 20 to 40 percent error will do the work.

Comment: think of normals on ellipse

Comment: @jimjim sorry, couldn't find how normals are useful in my case. No property of ellipse is uniform across all the angles as far as I know.

Comment: There are two problems in the picture in your question. The first is that the the waves bunch up as the curvature increases (this is fixed by reparametrising by arc length), and the second is that the peaks seem to lean over as curvature increases, by which I mean the peaks point away from the origin, not away from the surface of the ellipse. To fix this you need to use normal vectors rather than just polar coordinates. @whyhosamwhy's answer below implements both of these changes.

Comment: do it in polar form, the equations you have will not work for what you are asking,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an implementation of @David Sheard idea.

It is an ellipse $ p(t) = (a \cos(t) , b \sin(t) ) $ with $a = 15, b = 8 $.

At each point, the unit normal is computed $n(t) = \dfrac{(b \cos(t), a \sin(t))}{\sqrt{ b^2 \cos^2(t) + a^2 \sin^2(t) }} $

The arc length from $0$ to $t$ is computed

$ s(t) = \displaystyle \int_0^t \sqrt{ a^2 \sin(\tau)^2 + b^2 \cos^2(\tau) } \ d\tau $

And the point on the final curve is defined by

$ q(t) = p(t) + c \cos \bigg(20 (2 \pi)  \bigg( \dfrac{s(t)}{S} \bigg) \bigg) n(t) $

where $S = s(2 \pi) $ and $c$ is the amplitude of the sine wave, $c=2$.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to re-parameterise your ellipse by arc-length. It is not possible to do this using elementary functions (polynomials, exponentials, trig, etc), you have to use elliptic functions. Check out [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805541/arc-length-of-an-ellipse) to see how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Would have be nice if any elementary function existed. Do you know any such functions? Accuracy is not important in my case, even 20 to 40 percent error will do the work.

Comment: [This paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2021/5546666/) claims to approximate elliptic functions by trig functions, but it looks even more complicated to implement. Two alternative options which may be better in practice: 1) the software you are using may very well have elliptic functions already implemented, or you could change to different software which does. 2) If the software you are using has a numerical integration function, you could numerically compute the arc length and us this to re-parameterise your ellipse.